# Import multiple collections (nodejs, mongodb)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm new with node.js and mongodb.
In my database, I have several collections (one for users, one for article, and in the future one more...).

In my server.js file, I would like to be able to write in each of these collections. 
Here is the code I use, but I'm not able to access all my collections... Have you an ideas to make that possible?

```
var databaseUrl = "mydb"; // "username:password@example.com/mydb"
var collections = ["users", "article", "reports", "archery"]
var db = require("mongojs").connect(databaseUrl, collections);
```

Thank you

Comment: I don't understand the question, are you trying to `db.users.find()` and it's not working?

Comment: At the beginning, I only had:
    var collections = ["users", "reports"]
And I was able to use db.users.find()
Now I add the others collections and I want to know if it's the right way or not, I want to be able to do db.users.find() and db.article.find().

Comment: Try it out. I think that should work. You can even dynamically open a collection by saying `db.collection('collection_name').find()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to know all of your collections in advance to use `mongojs`, you can access a collection dynamically using `db.collection('name_of_collection')` and use it just like an existing collection. This call will also cache it so that next time, you can say `db.name_of_collection`.

There's a bunch of examples at their git hub page:
https://github.com/gett/mongojs

Good luck.